# Error in xml format when exporting report - Magento

Tags: xml, magento, export

I have a problem, when exporting the report (Reports -> Sales -> Billed), the file that is downloaded is as follows:

- If I export as CSV: `invoiced.csv-, attachment`
- If I export as XML: `invoiced.xml-, attachment`

I can not understand why the files are coming with "`-, attachment`" at the end. 
And the strange thing is that this only occurs on:

- Reports -> Sales -> Billed
- Reports -> Sales -> Coupons

The remaining of reporting options, is working correctly.

Has anyone experienced this or have any idea what is the cause of problem?

Thank you for listening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution

Open the file:

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php

**change:**

-> setHeader ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename =, true "' $ fileName.. '"')

**to:**

-> setHeader ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename =';, true "'$ fileName.."')

*Basically adds, there in $ fileName ',' getting $ fileName '";'*.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below file

```
magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Report\SalesController.php


1) exportInvoicedCsvAction()
2) exportInvoicedExcelAction()
```

check **fileName** in both function it should be

```
$fileName   = 'invoiced.csv';//for csv

$fileName   = 'invoiced.xml';//for excel xml
```

hope this help you

Comment: The Variable $ fileName was correct value but ... 

I did a workaround,  "kludge"
Changed to: 
$ this-> _prepareDownloadResponse ($ fileName, $ grid-> getExcelFile ($ fileName)); 
for 
$ this-> _prepareDownloadResponse (str_replace ("- attachment", "", $ fileName, $ grid-> getExcelFile ($ fileName))); 

But his comment was werent helpful, Thanks (: